# Blender Synchronizing Object Render

Tags: rendering, animation, geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface, render-layers

I'm creating an animation, which has a two geometry nodes setups, which both share the same nodes below. For some reason, it's taking blender 2-3 times as long (25-30 seconds before v.s. 85 seconds now) to render frames  than before due to it having to synchronize each of the geometry nodes objects. I don't remember having to deal with this issue before in previous animations with geometry nodes and I'm wondering if there's a way to get rid of the syncing or shorten the time used for syncing. I tried to lower the subdivisions from 2 to 1 here but it didn't affect much. How can I fix this so I can speed up my render times?

I'm using Blender 3.6.0[image]

Comment: 1) please upload images which are easy to read and not blurred like yours 2) please upload your blend file so we don't have to rebuild all manually.  thx.